# А почему именно 1710 нужно установить в energy_threshold?

Tags: python

Сейчас изучаю SpeechRecognition, и запустил вот такой код:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()

try:
    print("A moment of silence, please...")
    with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Set minimum energy threshold to {}".format(r.energy_threshold))
while True:
    print("Say something!")
    with m as source: audio = r.listen(source)
    print("Got it! Now to recognize it...")
    try:
        # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
        value = r.recognize_google(audio)

        print("You said {}".format(value))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Oops! Didn't catch that")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Uh oh! Couldn't request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Этот код пишет, чтобы установить минимальную звуковую энергию для записи в 1710, то есть `energy_threshold = 1710`. До этого весь день голову ломал, потому что этот код:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

text = r.recognize_google(audio,language="ru-RU")
print (text)
```

Не работал, выдавал следующее:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side   
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

И самое интересное, этот самый `energy_threshold` по умолчанию установлен в 300.

И все это вчера работало... сегодня перестал работать и просит, чтобы установить в 1710...

Хорошо, допустим, но а почему именно 1710 ? Откуда это значение берется?

Сообщает о 1710 вот эта часть:

```
 print("Set minimum energy threshold to {}".format(r.energy_threshold))

r.energy_threshold
```

это:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
```

Внутри `Recognizer()` нету кода, чтобы сообщать про `energy_threshold`, я не нашел...

Объясните пожалуйста, откуда берется значение для **energy_threshold**=1710... и почему именно **1710**... при том "минимум"

И хочу сказать, что я вчера вообще не трогал эти настройки с `energy_threshold`-ами... вообще! просто сам по себе бац - сломался...

Comment: а вот теперь опять перестал работать, и тот код который сообщает про energy_threshold установить минимум в 1100... как тааак ? не понимаю

Comment: каждый раз пишет разное значение...

Comment: Стандартного значения нет, это минимальное значение при котором звук распознаётся как речь. Меняться он может если много шумов и микрофон хреновый, да много из-за чего. По хорошему перед распознаванием надо делать обработку звука или накладывать фильтры. Например в OBS куча таких примочек и даже пожилой микрофон может зазвучать как стримерский, если повозиться.

Comment: @DiMithras, а может ли что эта проблема возникает из за того что у меня наушники и веб-камера (с микрофоном) установлены одновременно ?

Comment: Вряд ли они пишут одновременно, но если звук с вебки получаете, не удивительно, что значения прыгают. Вебка на слух воспринимается очень плохо, а для алгоритмов это вообще тьма тьмущая.

Comment: @DiMithras спасибо огромное!